# How to subtract date in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have date-time field in my database like that 2023-01-18 and I want to subtract this field from the current date.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: what kind of result do you want to get: differences in days/hours/minutes/seconds etc ?

Comment: Subtracting a date and time from another doesn't make sense; what are you expected the end result to therefore be? What is `2023-02-03 09:28:00 - 2021-07-10 11:57:00`? `0002-07-27 21:31:00`? `2` (because they are 2023 - 2021= 2)? Something else?

Comment: I want to get result when difference from this field less than one minute

Comment: @Larnu, e.g. interval  '1-06' year to month, or '572 21:31:00.000000' day to second, depending on what you ask for. (ISO/ANSI SQL.)

Comment: @userfh, do you mean you want the difference in minutes?

Comment: @jarlh yes in minutes

Comment: This is not as simple as it sounds to do correctly.  What exact type is your column?  If it is a timestamp type, what timezone is your connection using?  If a datetime type, what timezone is the data you stored in?

Comment: @ysth yes it is datetime type

Comment: And how are you setting it?  What timezone is your data in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to calculate the difference:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, localtimestamp, columnname) AS difference
```

`localtimestamp` gives you the current date and time (without timezone information.) You can also use `current_timestamp` if you want the timezone.

https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-mysql/